# Как посчитать количество символов по адресу в DS

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm, дизассемблирование

Скажите пожалуйста, как мне посчитать, какая длина строчки, зная только ее адрес?
Можно ли сделать символьную проверку? Что-то типа счётчика, который бы прибавлялся до тех пор, пока проверяемый символ не будет равен "0"(конец строки). 
Моё предложение :

```
Повтор до тех пор пока ([myHEAP]+i не равно 0){
i++;
}
Вывод "длина строки = "+i;
Конец.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется что строка "A l e x a n d e r" не ровна 2 :( А где результат будет?

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 

     option casemap :none 
     __UNICODE__ equ 1 
     include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
     include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
      include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
     include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
     include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
     include C:\masm32\include\winextra.inc
     include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
     include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
     includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
     includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib 
     includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
     includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
        ;includelib C:\masm32\lib\winextra.lib
     includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
     HeapSize PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD

     Main   PROTO 
     .data 
     Heap dd 0
     nim dd ?
    _mov db ?
    _mov2 db ?
    hMylp1 dd 0
    hConsoleInput DWORD ?
    hConsoleOutput DWORD ?
    NumberOfCharsWritten DWORD ?
     .code 

     start: 

     invoke Main 
     invoke ExitProcess,0 
     Main proc 
     invoke GetProcessHeap
     mov Heap,eax

    invoke HeapAlloc,Heap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,300h
    mov hMylp1,eax

        push eax

        mov [hMylp1], input()

        pop eax
        mov eax, [hMylp1]
        invoke AllocConsole
        invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        mov hConsoleInput, EAX
        invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
        mov hConsoleOutput, EAX
        ;mov eax, sizeof hMylp1
    push es         ; сохраняем es на всякий случай
    push ds
    pop  es         ; es=ds
    mov  edi,[hMylp1]
    mov  ecx,300h   ; Максимальная длина буфера
    xor  eax,eax    ; Будем искать 0, вообще достаточно al=0, но xor eax,eax быстрее
    cld             ; Сканировать на увеличение адресов (df=0)
    repne scasb     ; Сканируем строку, пока не найдем 0
                    ; es:edi - указывает на конец строки, ecx=остаток после конца строки
    mov  eax,300h
    sub  eax,ecx    ; eax=длина строки, так же можно использовать edi-адрес_строки
    pop  es
        invoke WriteConsoleA, hConsoleOutput, [hMylp1], 2, 0, 0
    invoke HeapFree,Heap,NULL,hMylp1

     Main endp 
     end start
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А DS кстати регистр сегмента, в нем не может быть адреса. В нем селектор сегмента данных, а полный адрес формируется из селектора и регистра общего назначения

Comment: Кстати, я присмотрелся к вашему первому скрину, у вас там отладка очень удачно стоит на pop eax который вы делаете после input. зачем вы вообще делаете push eax перед input и pop после ? input() его портит ? А что он в него кладет. На скрине у вас там значение 7 - что как раз равно длине строки в символах ... На других длинах строк гляньте, может вам и считать ничего не надо, потому как он в eax вам готовую длину возвращает. Остается ее умножить на 2 если нужна длина в байтах, а не в символах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если длина строки заранее была неизвестна - то единственный способ узнать ее длину - найти в ней 0. Для этого удобно использовать инструкцию [SCASB](http://www.kolasc.net.ru/cdo/programmes/assembler/scas.html). Данная инструкция с префиксом repne сканирует буфер, адресуемый es:edi до тех пор пока не найдет байт, указанный в al (или ищет первый отличный от al байт, при использовании с префиксом repe). При этом в ecx задается максимальный размер буфера, инструкция его уменьшает по мере сканирования строки и останавливается если нашла то что искали или ecx стал равен 0.

```
push es         ; сохраняем es на всякий случай
push ds
pop  es         ; es=ds
mov  edi,адрес-строки
mov  ecx,300h   ; Максимальная длина буфера
xor  eax,eax    ; Будем искать 0, вообще достаточно al=0, но xor eax,eax быстрее
cld             ; Сканировать на увеличение адресов (df=0)
repne scasb     ; Сканируем строку, пока не найдем 0
                ; es:edi - указывает на конец строки, ecx=остаток после конца строки
mov  eax,300h
sub  eax,ecx    ; eax=длина строки, так же можно использовать edi-адрес_строки
pop  es
```

P.S. для сканирования строк, сохраненных в UTF-16 надо использовать поиск двух нулевых байт подряд, т.е. SCASW при AX=0.

Comment: а этот код пойдёт с DS?

Comment: scasb работает исключительно с es:edi, поэтому я копирую ds в es в самом начале

Comment: посмотрите что у меня не правильно, тему обновил.

Comment: ну вот на картинке 2 :( Может input в конец строки 0 не добавляет? Тему обновил

Comment: подождите а может будет это из-за того, что строчку Alexander Input сохраняется как "41 00 6C 00|65 00 78 00|61 00 6E 00|64 00 65 00 72" и ваш код определяет как строку только первый символ A(41) так как последующий символ равен 00?

Comment: Scasw помог огромное вам спасибо ♥ ♥ ♥ :D

Comment: @AlexRudenkiy Тогда удаляем лишние комментарии. ибо http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2408/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82